# Javascript Scrollbar Disappears?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, jscrollpane, jcarousel

Thanks for taking the time to read.

I am having some problems with **JScrollPane** and image reinitialize with 1 page on my website.

Under the Blog Section, you can scroll down the first default article (Dog Days are Over),
but once you click on any of the Articles with images (Rabbit Heart) .. the scrollbar disappears.

It then reappears if you click on an article with no image or the first article.

The above problem seems to only occur on brand new cache. Any ideas?

I have tried disable Cufon but the same problem remains, its definitely an image problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the Cufon text is larger than the plain-text that it replaced. If this is the case then it's also possible that the container for the "Rabbit Heart" article is not large enough for a scroll-bar, then Cufon hits the text, making the text too long for the container, but since the JScrollPane code has already run the extra text gets clipped.

Comment: This happens to any article I put a picture in, other than the default one. Could it be a Cufon problem or an image reinitialize problem?

Comment: I went ahead and tried adding twice as much article length, still having same problem.

Comment: It's a strange issue, intermittent, it works about half the time in my Chrome 17 browser. I'll think about it and get back to you if anything smart pops into my brain.

Comment: I believe I have specified the width/height of the image with CSS on line 1559 of style.css

Comment: Yeah I saw that so I deleted my comment as it was invalid. I'll think about it though.

Comment: Appreciate the help so far, if you could help me initialize jscrollpane images everytime a jcarousel button is clicked, im sure it could work.

Comment: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/dynamic_content.html. Check-out this demo. It saves an reference to the widget and updates it when elements are dynamically inserted into the pane. Hope this helps. Also there is this: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/known_issues.html. But I think you are loading the CSS before the JS anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the container div of Rabbit Heart has the class of jScrollPaneScrollable

Comment: That's correct, for some reason it's not recognizing a need for a scrollbar.